# Объявление и реализация шаблонного класса в разных файлах

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

У меня есть определение шаблонного класса в файле `foo.cpp`, который **НЕ** включает в себя файл `bar.h`, который по замыслу должен содержать объявление того же шаблонного класса:

```
// foo.cpp

template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    void public_method() {
        // ...implementation...
    }
private:
    int private_member = 42;
};

template class A<int>;

// bar.h

template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    void public_method();
};
```

Будет ли всё работать в файле `baz.cpp`, если объявление (как видно) не содержит никаких приватных членов и в `baz.cpp` к ним не обращаются? Если не будет, то надо ли добавлять инициализатор для приватного члена (`= 42`) в объявление в `bar.h`?

```
// baz.cpp

#include "bar.h"


int main() {
    A<int> x;
    x.public_method();
}
```

У меня всё компилируется, но есть сомнения в валидности кода.

Comment: будет неопределенное поведение из-за нарушения ODR

Comment: Очень **определённое** поведение. В main будет выделяться другое количество памяти стека. А функция будет думать, что всё в порядке. Итого - в main другие переменные будут портить значение переменной "привидение" (**private_member**).

Comment: @AlexGlebe: Это весьма наивные ожидания. Неопределенное поведение - это **неопределенное** поведение. Ничего определенного в нем нет. Многие современные компиляторы (если не все они) умеют и, по возможности, будут хранить объекты малого размера в регистрах процессора (да, даже если это экземпляры классов). Поэтому при чем здесь вдруг какая-то "память стека" - не ясно.

Comment: @AnT Я выдал всего-лишь наглядный пример, что точно всё не-валидно. И этот способ надо переделать.

Answer (score 2):

Язык С++ не допускает различных определений одного и того же шаблона. Все определения одного и того же шаблона в программе обязаны совпадать.

На самом деле описание требуемой степени совпадения - весьма [нетривиальная тема](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12), но все начинается с того, что множественные определения таких сущностей [должны состоять из одной и той же последовательности токенов](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12.12). В вашем случае нарушено уже это, самое простое требование.

Ваш код формально является некорректным. Даже если ваш компилятор не отловил эту некорректность, все рано поведение вашего кода не определено.

P.S. Наличие или отсутствие инициализатора по умолчанию для поля `private_member` здесь никакой роли не играет.

Answer (score 0):

Минимально пример можно исправить так:

```
// foo.cpp

template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    void public_method() {
        // ...implementation...
    }
private:
    int private_member = 42;
};

template class A<int>;

// bar.h

template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    void public_method();
private:
    int private_member = 42;
};

// baz.cpp

#include "bar.h"


int main() {
    A<int> x;
    x.public_method();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Минимально можно исправить так:

```
// foo.cpp

template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    void public_method() {
        // ...implementation...
    }
private:
    int private_member = 42;
};

template class A<int>;

// bar.h

template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    void public_method();
private:
    int private_member;
};

// baz.cpp

#include "bar.h"


int main() {
    A<int> x;
    x.public_method();
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Всё будет работать, т.к. это объявление, а не определение. Ничего исправлять не надо

Answer (score -1):

Разные декларации класса ведут к разному размеру класса в стеке. Итого методы будут думать, что выставляют значения правильно, а внешние функции будут пользоваться памятью как своей. Итого конфликт адресный.

bar.h

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    void public_method()volatile  ;
    int V()const volatile  ;
};
```

foo.cpp

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    void public_method()volatile {
        // ...implementation...
      private_member = -7 ;
    }
    int V(void)const volatile{return private_member;}
private:
    volatile  int private_member = 42;
};

template class A<int>;
```

baz.cpp

```
# include <iostream>
#include "bar.h"

int main() {
    volatile  long  int killer;
    volatile  A<int> x;
    std::cout<<"0:x.V = "<<x.V()<<std::endl;
    x.public_method();
    std::cout<<"1:x.V = "<<x.V()<<std::endl;    
    killer = 666 ;
    std::cout<<"2:x.V = "<<x.V()<<std::endl;
}
```

Результат :

```
>g++ foo.cpp baz.cpp
>./a.out
0:x.V = 1074212864
1:x.V = -7
2:x.V = 170745
```

Публичный метод поставил своё значение. А локальная переменная **killer** всё испортила.

Есть много способов правильно разграничить публичные функции и исполнение. Например, удалённое наследование:

bar.h

```
template<typename T>
class P ;

template<typename T>
class A {
public:
  A();
  ~A();
    void public_method();
protected :
  P<T> * p ;
};

template class A<int>;
```

foo.cpp

```
# include <iostream>
# include "bar.h"

template<typename T>
class P {
public:
    void public_method() {
        // ...implementation...
      std::cout<<"Hi!\n";
    }
private:
    int private_member = 42;
};

template class P<int>;

template<typename T>
A<T>::A():p(new P<T>){}

template<typename T>
A<T>::~A<T>(){delete p;}

template<typename T>
void A<T>::public_method(){p->public_method();}
```

baz.cpp

```
#include "bar.h"

int main() {
    A<int> x;
    x.public_method();
}
```

Функции класса P и переменные не выводятся в заголовочные файлы. Как говорят на "зелёной миле" : всё, что происходит, там и остаётся.